# How to change the "isOnlineMeeting" from to true of a microsoft event through ms graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, graph-explorer

I have an event. It has the property "isOnlineMeeting" set to true, but when I run a PATCH request, setting it to false, nothing happens. It doesn't display an error, just the response from the graph api server, where "isOnlineMeeting" is true. Please help!

I have tried to run a PATCH request to the [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{event_id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/%7Bevent_id%7D) endpoint, this is my code:
`{ "isOnlineMeeting": false }`
But when it is successfully completed it doesn't give an error, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isOnlineMeeting` is `false` by default. `True` if this event has online meeting information (that is, onlineMeeting points to an onlineMeetingInfo resource), `false` otherwise.

After you set `isOnlineMeeting` to `true`, Microsoft Graph initializes onlineMeeting. Subsequently Outlook ignores any further changes to `isOnlineMeeting`, and the meeting remains available online.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties